# jQuery while post counter false respectively success 3 , 4 , 1

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asynchronous, while-loop

hi i delete async:false code and not good working i want success and other post 
1,2,3,4,5,6

async:false mozilla good working , chrome is freeze.
Now my code how i can success 1 success 2 success 3 succes 4
Now working success 3 , success 4 , success 1 , success 0

Example code JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/blck_/2t4utuc5/35/

```
$('#click').click(function(){
var counter = 0;
var toplamDeger = 5;

while (counter < toplamDeger) {    

     (function(counter) {

         $.ajax({       
              url:'/echo/html/',        
              type: 'POST', 
              success: function(sonuc){
                  //$('#sonuc'+counter).html(counter);
                  alert(counter);

                  //Değer artmıyor counter
                  },
              error:function(){
                  //$('#sonuc'+count).html(counter);
                  alert(counter);

                 }
               })}(counter))

    counter++;

}})
```

Comment: Why are you using an [`IIFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) for this?

Comment: @leemo i want get success the number of cycles

Comment: Without seeing more context regarding your question (why request order is relevant here?), hard to give more relevant answer than using some kind of logic like that e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/dfnLycLd/

Comment: Thanks for comments , i fixed @A.Wolff code very thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** @A.Wolff's jsFiddle in the question comments provides a much better way to think about `AJAX` than the below. The below is an attempt to point out some errors in the code, without changing your original code too much but @A.Wolff's example is a far better way to think about structuring your AJAX calls.

Welcome to SO. As this is one of your first questions, Im giving you an answer that explains some things.

There are a number of things you're misunderstanding about AJAX here.

The first is that the  **A** in AJAX means **asynchronous** so while jQuery provides an `async:false` option you shoulder not being using it inside a loop.

the second is that `async:false` is deprecated see the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Now if you're going to use it anyway you need to understand that `async:false` should only be used for single AJAX calls (never calls in a loop) and **only** if there is some reason the call HAS to be completed before the user can interact again.

It has been deprecated as it defeats the purpose of what AJAX is designed to do: you'd be better off redirecting to a new page than using AJAX for anything that requires this.

You're obviously just testing AJAX at the moment (I certainly **hope** this is not something you're going to use in a production environment, no matter how small).

I assume you put the AJAX call inside an `IIFE` because you thought that you didnt have access to `counter` in the `.ajax()` scope. You **do**. Here is a rewrite that may help you:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var toplamDeger = 5;

    while (counter < toplamDeger) {    



         $.ajax({
              async: false,       
              url:'/echo/html/',        
              type: 'POST', 
              success: function(sonuc){
                  //$('#sonuc'+counter).html(counter);

                  alert(counter);

                  //Değer artmıyor counter
                  },
              error: function(jqXHR, statusText, errorText){
                  //$('#sonuc'+counter).html(counter); //you had #sonuc-count in your code - it should be counter

                  //This will tell you what went wrong
                  alert(statusText + "\n" + errorText);
                  alert(counter);

                 }
               }); // End AJAX

    counter++;

    } // end while
}); //end Click
```

**IMPORTANT:** As I said above this is **not** how you should be using `ajax`. But It may help you understand whats going wrong.